# VLOOKUP is returning all NAs even though some values are located in search

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am trying to do a vlookup in excel but everything is coming back as NAs. I know this is not correct because a simple control find shows me that some of the values are located in it. I am trying to find unique identifiers. The code I am using is below.

[image: vlookup]

Is there something obvious that I am missing? I am trying to look up if column b is located anywhere in l through t.

Thanks

Comment: VLOOKUP(lookup_value,table_array,COL_INDEX_NUM, [range lookup]) Can I ask that the 13th column in your selection $L:$T contains the values you are looking up? I believe this will be column X?

Answer (score 1):

L:T is a range of nine columns. You are asking for column 13.

edit: I just reread your question - that is not quite how Vlookup works. Using VLookup looks up a table and returns the nth column result back where n is the offset starting with the first column in your second parameter. If you want achieve your result with VLOOKUP you would need to wrap them in `IFERROR` or `IF(ISNA())` functions depending on your version.

But a better way would probably be to concatenate the columns and do a find. Ifd Find returns a non-error, then you have yourself a match. Use IFERROR if your version allows it to wrap. Something like this:

```
=IFERROR(FIND(B1,CONCATENATE(L1:T1)),"")
```

or

```
=IFERROR(FIND(B1,CONCATENATE(L1&M1&N1&O1&P1&Q1&R1&S1&T1)),"")
```

Comment: As Alan has stated, I "think" you are incorrectly thinking the column value is the column index relative to the entire sheet, and not the selection. I base this off the fact your screenshot starts from column B, and cdrCallId is column 13. If you change the column index to 2 (it would match on cdrCallId).

Comment: I just did 
                         =IFERROR(FIND(B22,CONCATENATE(m:n)),"") 
within that worksheet. However, everything is blank. I assume that is not expected. To be clear, in this scenario, I want to search all of m or n if b is located in it and the same value appears.

Comment: Try the ampersand version. I had some issues with Concatenate just now. If it is blank, it means that either the concatenate didn't work, or the find didn't match. You can split out the concatenate separately to test. But use the ampersands to join the string and you should be fine.

Comment: @Alan, I think the requirement is to look at whole columns, so CONCATENATE isn’t going to work for that - I suggest COUNTIF - see my answer

Comment: Yes @barryhoudini - if you want to match whole columns, then yours is the right way.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know whether the value `B221 exists in columns`L`to`T`then`COUNTIF` will probably be a better option

`=COUNTIF($L:$T,B22)`

That will give you a number - obviously zero means no match